# Как инициализировать std::map с массивом структур внутри?

Tags: c++, массивы, map, инициализация

Есть такой код:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

struct Cell { // Простая структурка
    Cell(int x, int y) : X(x), Y(y) {}

    int8_t X = 0;
    int8_t Y = 0;
};

Cell q[4]({0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}); // Здесь всё хорошо
Cell w[4] = {Cell(1, 1), Cell(1, 1), Cell(1, 1), Cell(1, 1)}; // И здесь всё хорошо

std::map <uint8_t, Cell> testMap{ // И так всё предсказуемо работает
    {0, {0, 0}},
    {1, {1, 1}},
    {2, {2, 2}}
};

std::map <uint8_t, Cell[4]> figureDictionary{ // А здесь ругается
    {0, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}},
    {1, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}}
};

std::map <uint8_t, Cell[4]> figureDictionary2 = { // И здесь ругается
    {0, {Cell(0, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(0, 0)}},
    {1, {Cell(1, 1), Cell(1, 1), Cell(1, 1), Cell(1, 1)}}
};
```

Говорит, отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора, соответствующие etc.. Хотя по идее он мог бы развернуть скобки довольно однозначно.

Отчего так? MSVS 2022, С++20 (если это вдруг важно)

UPD. 5.12.23

По совету попробовал воспользоваться std::array или std::vector. Картина любопытная - простая замена одного массива на другой результата не даёт, конструкторы в них по-разному выглядят (как я это понимаю)

А вот когда изладил код на std::array - попробовал поменять его обратно на простой встроенный массив - и всё заработало почему-то:

```
#include <array>
#include <map>

struct Cell {
    Cell(int x, int y) : X(x), Y(y) {}

    int8_t X = 0;
    int8_t Y = 0;
};

/*
std::array<Cell, 4> q0{ Cell(0, 0), Cell(0, 1), Cell(-1, 0), Cell(-1, 1) };
std::array<Cell, 4> q1{ Cell(1, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(0, 1), Cell(-1, 0) };
std::array<Cell, 4> q2{ Cell(1, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(-1, 0), Cell(-1, 1) };
std::array<Cell, 4> q3{ Cell(1, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(-1, 0), Cell(-1, -1) };
std::array<Cell, 4> q4{ Cell(1, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(-1, 0), Cell(-2, 1) };
*/

Cell q0[4] { Cell(0, 0), Cell(0, 1), Cell(-1, 0), Cell(-1, 1) };
Cell q1[4] { Cell(1, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(0, 1), Cell(-1, 0) };
Cell q2[4] { Cell(1, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(-1, 0), Cell(-1, 1) };
Cell q3[4] { Cell(1, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(-1, 0), Cell(-1, -1) };
Cell q4[4] { Cell(1, 0), Cell(0, 0), Cell(-1, 0), Cell(-2, 1) };

const std::map <uint8_t, std::array <Cell, 4>> figureDictionary = {
    {0, {q0[0], q0[1], q0[2], q0[3]}},
    {1, {q1[0], q1[1], q1[2], q1[3]}},
    {2, {q2[0], q2[1], q2[2], q2[3]}},
    {3, {q3[0], q3[1], q3[2], q3[3]}},
    {4, {q4[0], q4[1], q4[2], q4[3]}}
};
```

В принципе мои задачи такой вариант закрывает, однако если кто-то расскажет, почему и отчего так происходит - будет здорово

Comment: Используйте  `std::array<Cell,4>` вместо `Cell[4]`. Встроенный массив `Cell[4]` - плохой из-за необходимости совместимости с С. (Сходу не могу найти ссылку, на обсуждение.)

Comment: Добавил немного доп. информации в вопрос. std::vector и std::array, конечно, более дружелюбны, что ли, однако конкретно здесь конкретно мне по сути не нужны их богатые возможности. Да и разобраться ещё хочется, почему происходят разные вещи. Благодарю за подсказку :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Короткий ответ**: никак.

**Подробнее**.

Конструктор

```
map( std::initializer_list<value_type> init,
     const Compare& comp = Compare(),
     const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

принимает на вход список инициализаторов для типа `map::value_type`, то есть `pair<const K, V>`. В вашем случае это `pair<const uint8_t, Cell[4]>`.

Поэтому ваш вопрос сводится с другому - можно ли инциализировать пару, содержащую массив фиксированной длины?

Пробуем:

```
typedef std::pair <const uint8_t, Cell[4]> Pair;
Pair p{0, w};
```

получаем отлуп.

Если отвлечься от того, что пишет компилятор, и посмотреть [справочник](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), то окажется, что нужный конструктор `pair(const uint8_t&, const Cell (&)[4])` вызывается **при условии**

```
std::is_copy_constructible_v<const uint8_t> == true && 
std::is_copy_constructible_v<Cell[4]> == true
```

Пробуем:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_copy_constructible_v<const uint8_t> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_copy_constructible_v<Cell[4]> << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

получаем

```
1
0
```

Вот и ответ - массив в С++ не имеет констуктора копирования. Поэтому нельзя в конструкторе `pair(const T1& x, const T2& y) : first(x), second(y) {}` инициализировать поле `second` в случае, когда `T2` является массивом `Cell[4]`.

Аналогичная проблема с конструктором, который "двигает" параметры: `pair(const uint8_t&&, Cell (&&)[4])` вызывается **при условии**

```
std::is_move_constructible_v<const uint8_t> == true && 
std::is_move_constructible_v<Cell[4]> == true
```

Пробуем:

```
void main() {
    std::cout << std::is_move_constructible_v<const uint8_t> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_move_constructible_v<Cell[4]> << std::endl;
}
```

получаем

```
1
0
```

Другими словами, поле `second` в паре `pair<const uint8_t, Cell[4]>` не инициализировать ни копированием, ни сдвигом.

Почему в таком случае работает инициализатор для `map<uint8_t,array<Cell, 4>>`? Для класса array<Cell, 4> список `{q0[0], q0[1], q0[2], q0[3]}` является инициализатором, из него конструируется объект типа `std::array<Cell, 4>`. Так как у этого типа есть и конструктор копирования, и конструктор сдвига, то для каждой из пар в инциализаторе `map` вызывается конструктор `pair(const uint8_t&& x, array<Cell,4>&& y )`, и компилятор не ругается.

Comment: Я, конечно, не настоящий сварщик, но: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20231023-00/?p=108916

Comment: @VladD да, можно и так извернуться, но ИМХО `array<Cell,4>` гораздо лучше, чем `tuple`. Как минимум, нагляднее.

Comment: @PakUula, благодарю за такой большой, развёрнутый ответ, это именно то, чего я и хотел. Главное - понять принцип, увидеть, как оно работает и почему. Очень здорово, что вы нашли время на это

Comment: @VladD, очень любопытный способ, попробую его раскурить в ближайшее время, спасибо